# How to render .cshtml as Email Body using SendGrid+MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to send email, normal email I am able to send.
But now I have send a template(.cshtml) in email.

Please tell me to how can I do this.

Here is my code:

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult SendEmailDeviceInfoDisplay(List<String> deviceDatailData)
{
    string body = "";
    var emailContoller = new EmailController();
    string email = deviceDatailData[9];
    body = "<html>Event Name: " + deviceDatailData[0] +"</html>";

    var sendEmail = emailContoller.SendDeviceAndEventInfoMail(email, body);
    ViewBag.info = deviceDatailData[8];
    return PartialView("SendEmailConformationDisplay");
}
```

**SendGrid Method:**

```
public string SendDeviceAndEventInfoMail(string email, string body)
{
    var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
    myMessage.From = new MailAddress("anita.mehta@test.com");
    List<String> recipients = new List<String> { email };
    myMessage.AddTo(recipients);
    myMessage.Subject = "Information";
    myMessage.Html = body;
    var transportWeb = new Web(nc);
    transportWeb.Deliver(myMessage);
    return "done";
}
```

**Ajax Call:**

```
$(function () {
    var loggedInEmailId = $('#buildingSession').val();
    $('#sendAsEmailDeviceConformationDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: '27.5em',
        position: { my: 'top', at: 'top+150' },
        opacity: 100,
        resizable: false,
        //title: 'Product',
        modal: true,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog | ui).hide();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Overview/SendEmailDeviceInfoDisplay',
                traditional: true,
                data: data,                    
                success: function (result) {
                    $('.ui-button-text').hide();
                    $('#sendAsEmailDeviceConformationDialog').html(result);
                },
                error: function () {
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar requirement before and while it is possible to do I found more issues then it was worth so I went a different way. While this does not answer your question directly it is an alternate approach to the problem.

The basic idea was to avoid the complexity of using cshtml. So I used the following basic POCO object and stored it in a database:

```
public interface IEmailTemplate
{
    ... other db related fields
    string Name { get; set; }
    string FromEmail { get; set; }
    string FromDisplayName { get; set; }
    string Subject { get; set; }
    string TextMessage { get; set; }
    string HtmlMessage { get; set; }
    EmailPriority Priority { get; set; }
}
```

This allows me to manage the email without recompiling and re-deploying the project.

When I need to use it, I load the template and build out the email message. To help with that I use [SmartFormat.NET](https://github.com/scottrippey/SmartFormat.NET) to do data replacements using the follow logic:

```
    private string DataReplacements(string input, object args)
    {
        if (input.IsNullOrEmptyOrBlank())
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        return args != null ? Smart.Default.Format(input, args) : input;
    }

    subject = DataReplacements(template.Subject, dataModel);
    textMessage = DataReplacements(template.TextMessage, dataModel);
    htmlMessage = DataReplacements(template.HtmlMessage, dataModel);
```

Again while not answering your direct question this path gave me a lot more flexibility without the hassle.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But for me no need to save in database, I already have the data in my hand, I just  have to add the data in .cshtml and that .cshtml have to send in mail. Can you please tell me is it possible and if it is possible how can I do.